# Instability of Kuramoto solutions with Runge Kutta 4th order method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods

I am currently trying to solve the Kuramoto model:

$\ddot{\theta_i} = P_i - \alpha\dot{\theta_i} + K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}\sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$

I split this second order differential equation into two ODEs:

$$\dot{\omega_i} = P_i - \alpha\omega_i + K \underset{i \neq j}{\sum}sin(\theta_i - \theta_j) := f(\omega_i, \theta_i)$$
$$\dot{\theta_i} = \omega_i := g(\omega_i, \theta_i)$$

Next I use the Runge Kutta 4th order method by approximating $f(\omega_i, \theta_i)$ and $g(\omega_i, \theta_i)$.

My concrete situation is a three node topology, that is $\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2$ and $\theta_3$.

In this context, I consider P to be a 3-dim vector, W to be a 3-dim vector containing $\omega_i$ and T to b a 3-dim vector containing $\theta_i$.

My Runge kutta scheme then looks like:

$$k_1 = f(W, T)$$
$$l_1 = g(W,T)$$
$$k_2 = f(W+\frac{dt}{2}k_{1}, T + \frac{dt}{2}l_{1})$$
$$l_2 = g(W+\frac{dt}{2}k_{1}, T + \frac{dt}{2}l_{1})$$
$$k_3 = f(W+\frac{dt}{2}k_{2}, T + \frac{dt}{2}l_{2})$$
$$l_3 = g(W+\frac{dt}{2}k_{2}, T + \frac{dt}{2}l_{2})$$
$$k_4 = f(W+dtk_{3}, T + dtl_{3})$$
$$l_4 = g(W+dtk_{3}, T + dtl_{3})$$

Which gives me:

$$W(t+dt) = W(t) + \frac{dt}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4)$$ 
$$T(t+dt) = T(t) + \frac{dt}{6}(l_1 + 2l_2 + 2l_3 + l_4)$$

Now when I run my program with a short pertubation $P(1) = -4.8$ from $t = 40$ to $t = 42$ with $dt = \frac{1}{10}$ I get a "expected" stability result.
If I run my program with $P(1) = -4.8$ with $dt = \frac{1}{100}$ my solution completely blows up.
Similar, if I run my program with $P(1) = -4.9$ and $dt = \frac{1}{10}$ my solution blows up aswell.

The plots are shown below. ON the Y-axis I plot $\theta_1 - \theta_2$ and on the X-axis I plot the time. Any idea what could cause this instability?

[image: p1]
[image: p2]
[image: p3]
[image: p4]

Comment: Plots from top and down:
1) dt = 1e-1
2) dt = 1e-1 (so this is actually similar to plot 3), but on a shorter time scale)

Comment: In RK4, one sets $k_4= f(W+dt\cdot k_3, T + dt\cdot l_3)$ and $l_4= g(W+dt\cdot k_3, T + dt\cdot l_3)$, not $k_4= f(W+\frac12dt\cdot k_3, T + \frac12dt\cdot l_3)$ and $l_4= g(W+\frac12dt\cdot k_3, T + \frac12dt\cdot l_3)$ as written in your post.

Comment: I will edit that right away. I didn't mean to write that. I actually used the $k_4$ and $l_4$ that you wrote. But thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a different method, e.g. ode45? You may in fact need an implicit method to avoid instability.

Comment: Haven't so far tried any other method. I was advised to use the RK4 method, but I vaguely remember something about RK4 and stiff equations not being a good match. What is ode45?

Comment: ode45 is implemented in Matlab, it implements the Dormand-Price method, which is a 4th order RK type method with an embedded 5th order method, which is used for error estimates which are in turn used for dynamic step size selection. Matlab has several such methods; usually I default to ode45, if that breaks I try ode23s, and if that breaks then I think about what I can do to improve the situation. I think Octave implements a subset of these functions.

Comment: May I ask you why do you call this behaviour instability?

Comment: @Ian thanks for the detailed explanation. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @Evgeny I thought initially that it might be due to numerical instabaility, but frankly I am not sure what it is. It might be more accurate to say "incosistency" or simply just wierd behaviour. But I am sorry the confusive choice of word.

Comment: Well, I thought that you have some sort of reference article that you are checking and it is a source of your expectations. Does your integrator has fixed step? It might be a source of problems too, since fixed step isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Yes I do. I am comparing my results to a published paper concerning the analysis of the kuramoto model, and where they get a "unstable" solution; one that oscillates wildly after the pertubation, my solution simply runs off as seen above. I was told that the time step for this particular problem did not need any adaptive modifcation, but I will try it, however my plots above seem to indicate that the time step alone does not reflect the "behaviour" . Because with the same pertubation and a longer time step (last two plots), I end up with the same strange behaviour.